# can we use ${baseDir} placeholder in .Install4j file to replace the files path in entries tag

Tags: install4j

```
<entries>
      <fileEntry mountPoint="135" file="D:/Project/SampleProject/src/main/resources/SampleFiles/Driver/Driver.xls" overwriteMode="4" shared="false" fileMode="644" uninstallMode="0" overrideFileMode="false" overrideOverwriteMode="false" overrideUninstallMode="false" />
  </entries>
```

Here the path **D:/Project/SampleProject** is project's base directory , so is it possible to replace this path with the ${basedir} ?

I am Using install4j-maven-plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use compiler variables for that purpose.

On General Settings->Compiler variables, define a variable "baseDir", then you can use it with the syntax

```
${compiler:baseDir}
```

Note that if you select the "Make all paths relative" on General Settings->Project options, all files are made relative with respect to the project file and you may not need the variable if the project file is sinside the `baseDir` directory.